# Error when trying to run 'gradlew assembleRelease' in the Windows command line : jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision

Tags: gradle, react-native, aws-amplify, bundle-release-js-and-assets

I am trying to generate a .apk file of my react native project with the 'gradlew assembleRelease' command. I'm using AWS Amplify, which is where the naming collision seems to be coming from. The version of react native I'm running is 0.59.9.

I've tried creating a 'rn-cli.config.js' file in the root folder and replacing the code in the 'metro.config.js' with the 'rn-cli.config.js' code, which was unsuccessful. I can't remove the problem folder either because that creates more errors. 
I've also tried stopping and restarting the Gradle daemon, which hasn't worked either. This is the error I'm getting:

> Configure project :app
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.0) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.4.0.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a
>   default version of the build tools.
>
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
>   warning: the transform cache was reset.
>   error jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
>     Duplicate module name: myreactnativeapp_cfnlambda_ff57ce62
>     Paths: C:\Users\Kim\Desktop\myReactNativeApp\amplify\backend\interactions\reactLex\src\package.json collides with C:\Users\Kim\Desktop\myReactNativeApp\amplify#current-cloud-backend\interactions\reactLex\src\package.json
>
> This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
>
> Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'.
>     Process 'command 'cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

The code in the 'rn-cli.config.js' file looks like this:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

// blacklist is a function that takes an array of regexes and combines
// them with the default blacklist to return a single regex.

    module.exports = {
          resolver: {
                blacklistRE: blacklist([/amplify\/.*/])
          }
     };'
```

Do I need to change the code in the 'rn-cli.config.js' file or is there another workaround I could try?

Comment: try `blacklist([/amplify.*/]` (notice the missing \/)